# How to change position of innerhtml of div tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have div class like

```
<div role="columnheader" class="cell">Value

</div>
```

After that i am adding  some input as  achild to this div.

```
var Header = SomeMethod.text;
var inputChek = document.createElement("input");
inputChek.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
inputChek.setAttribute("id",col[i].id);
inputChek.onchange = MyMethod;
divClass[].appendChild(inputChek);
```

Then I am getting the my div somewhat like this

```
<div role="columnheader" class="cell">Value
    <input type="checkbox" id="Value" >
</div>
```

I am getting value before input tag. I want those value after input tag. Is there any way i can get this.

Answer example
    
        
        Value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`insertAdjacentElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) method and set `afterbegin` as first parameter.

```js
var inputChek = document.createElement("input");
inputChek.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
inputChek.setAttribute("id", 'Value');
document.querySelector('div').insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', inputChek);
```

```html
<div role="columnheader" class="cell">Value</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
divClass[].appendChild(inputChek);
```

use this:

```
divClass[].insertBefore( inputChek, divClass[].firstChild );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prepend` function https://jsfiddle.net/Lna6s2kz/1/

```
var Header = SomeMethod.text;
var inputChek = document.createElement("input");
inputChek.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
inputChek.setAttribute("id",col[i].id);
inputChek.onchange = MyMethod; 
divClass[].prepend(inputChek);
```